# Firebase auth using email/phone and passward

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

in my app at Login screen, I'd like to auth a user by two text inputs, where user could type either Email or Phone number, and password.

There's question, does it possible to auth user by phone and password? or phone auth uses by sending SMS code?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use phone auth using web sdk.

It doesn't support it but native sdk does.

Using react-native-firebase, you can use native sdk(android, ios) with react-native.

[react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes I'm using react-native-firebase. But I wanted to know how technically make auth throw phone and email as one textInput.

Comment: For now I found one way make it throw Linking multiple auth providers https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking